# Splitting pandas address into street and house numbers

Tags: regex, string, pandas

I have one dataframe with address data structured like this:

`tbm_a['address']`

```
Rue de blabla 20

Vossenstraat 7

Rue Père Jean 3 boite Z

Rue XSZFEFEF 331
```

I would like to split it in one column with the street and one with the house number.

I tried with this for loop, but failed:

```
import re
s = list(zip(tbm_a['address']))
for addr in s:
    tbm_a['street'] = re.findall('[^\d]*', addr)[0].strip()
    tbm_a['num'] = str(addr[len(street):].strip().split(' '))
```

Then I tried with this, and got the number:

```
tbm_a['address_num'] = tbm_a['address'].str.extract('(?P<number>\d+)', expand=True)
```

But I couldn't manage to get the street name. Any suggestions?

Comment: This might prove harder than it seems (maybe I'm wrong) but how are you going to handle things like `Vossenstraat 7b`? And is the number in `Rue Père Jean 3 boite Z` not `3 boite Z`? The house number isn't always simply a number. And simply splitting by digit can be tricky on stuff like `3rd Ave appt. 1000-4`

Comment: I'm afraid you're indeed right - but I do not believe I can account for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your data, you can do:

```
df.address.str.extract('(?P<Street>\D+) (?P<Number>\d+.*)')
```

Output:

```
          Street     Number
0  Rue de blabla         20
1   Vossenstraat          7
2  Rue Père Jean  3 boite Z
3   Rue XSZFEFEF        331
```

Remember this will fail if you have number in your street name, e.g. `5th avenue`.

Comment: Thank you! This is indeed it :)